# R: Kernel discriminant analysis and how to get the kernel cumulative density estimate and prediction(package ks)

Tags: r, kernel-smoothing

I use the R-package `ks` to do some kernel density estimation (the underlying kernel is the gaussian kernel and the default bin width selector is plug-in selection, although one also may get bin widths with cross validation techniques). I am interested to transform data with its estimated kernel cumulative density function **(Probability Integral Transformation)**. For the main function of this package, the "simple" kernel cumulative density estimator `kcde` I can use the function `predict.kcde` to transform my data with its estimated cumulative density function.

**Now** I want to try out the **kernel discriminant analysis** function `kda` of this package for data which appears to have several populations. 
This function `kda` calculates the binwidths, prior probabilities and the estimated kernel density function for the single populations.

My question is:
Is it possible to transform my data with the result from `kda`?
Would it be correct to use `kcde` and `predict.kcde` to each estimated population function (see plot below)?

Here some example code:

```
x <- c(rnorm.mixt(n=100, mus=1), rnorm.mixt(n=100, mus=-1))
x.gr <- rep(c(1,2), times=c(100,100))
y <- c(rnorm.mixt(n=100, mus=1), rnorm.mixt(n=100, mus=-1))
kda.gr <- kda(x, x.gr, eval.points=y)
compare(kda.gr$x.group, kda.gr$x.group.est, by.group=TRUE)
```

This is what I (visually) would get from the data above with plot.kda:
[image]

If you like you can find more informations about the package `ks` in this paper:
*ks: Kernel Density Estimation and Kernel Discriminant Analysis for Multivariate Data in R*  , by Tarn Duong
RCode Example is from the help pages of `kda`